# OOT Modules not showing up in GNURadio

Tags: gnuradio

Followed the instructions here to create an OOT module -

```
https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_Python

The cmake etc all works fine -
`cmake ../
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig`
```

But when I load up GNURadio the modules don’t appear. This is the output of the make install -

```
`gnuradio@cjswin ~/gr-tutorial/build >> sudo make install
[ 66%] Built target pygen_python_98246
[ 66%] Built target pygen_apps_9a6dd
[100%] Built target doxygen_target
Install the project…
– Install configuration: “Release”
– Up-to-date: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/lib/cmake/tutorial/tutorialConfig.cmake
– Up-to-date: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/include/tutorial/api.h
– Up-to-date: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tutorial/init.py
– Up-to-date: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tutorial/multiply_py_ff.py
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tutorial/init.pyc
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tutorial/multiply_py_ff.pyc
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tutorial/init.pyo
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tutorial/multiply_py_ff.pyo
– Up-to-date: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/tutorial_multiply_py_ff.xml
– Up-to-date: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/indexpage.xml
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/combine.xslt
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/namespacestd.xml
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/api_8h.xml
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/compound.xsd
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/index.xml
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/index.xsd
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/dir_d44c64559bbebec7f509842c48db8b23.xml
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/group__defs_8dox.xml
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/group__block.xml
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/dir_bebffc0fe021578eb5c034119e3e6a53.xml
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/xml/main__page_8dox.xml
– Up-to-date: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/files.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/jquery.js
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/tab_s.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/dir_d44c64559bbebec7f509842c48db8b23.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/modules.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/folderopen.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/navtree.css
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/tab_b.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/resize.js
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/group__defs_8dox.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/group__block.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/dir_bebffc0fe021578eb5c034119e3e6a53.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/dynsections.js
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/closed.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/tab_h.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/tab_a.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/open.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/bc_s.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/globals_defs.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/api_8h_source.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/files.js
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/navtreedata.js
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/api_8h.js
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/doxygen.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/tabs.css
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/index.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/sync_on.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/nav_f.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/sync_off.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/globals.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/navtreeindex0.js
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/splitbar.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/nav_h.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/navtree.js
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/doxygen.css
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/folderclosed.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/nav_g.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/bdwn.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/doc.png
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/api_8h.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/main__page_8dox.html
– Installing: /home/gnuradio/pybombs/share/doc/gr-tutorial/html/modules.js`
```

Some of the other forums have suggested changing the config.conf file, so I have gone to -

```
/home/.gnuradio/config.conf and added in the following (looking at the make install above my xml file seems to be going somewhere totally different to where the other gnuradio xml files are)
`[grc]
local_blocks_path=/home/gnuradio/pybombs/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks`

The other xml files are here - `/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks`

I have also tried doing the cmake with a prefix to that location -

`cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/share/gnuradio …/`
```

But this also has made no difference, i still can’t see the module when I"m in GNURadio.

Very much appreciate any help

Comment: "Followed the instructions here " - looks like you forgot to put the link?

Comment: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_Python

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your OOT module in the `src` folder of your pybombs prefix, for example:
When type `pybombs install gnuradio` this is installed into `~/pybombs/default/src/` (in this example the prefix name is `default`) so try to create your OOT module in this directory (`~/pybombs/default/src/gr-your-OOT/`) and continues working like you normally do it (this option works for me ...)

Answer (score 0):

> /home/.gnuradio/config.conf and added in the following (looking at the make install above my xml file seems to be going somewhere totally different to where the other gnuradio xml files are)
>
> ```
> [grc]
> local_blocks_path=/home/gnuradio/pybombs/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
> ```

The file that you need to edit is `/home/gnuradio/.gnuradio/config.conf`, you are missing one sub-directory.

> `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/share/gnuradio …/`

The correct install prefix in your case is `/home/gnuradio/pybombs/` and not `/usr/share/gnuradio/`. If you really want your module to be installed in `/usr` and blocks definitions in `/usr/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks` (I **do not** recommend this) then the prefix should be `/usr/` (without `/share/gnuradio`)

Comment: Thank you Vasil. My conf.config was in home/gnuradio/.gnuradio . The problem turned out to be in my xml file and I missed the fact that Gnuradio was showing me the parsing error when I opened it. Thanks again for your help!